# Sort method of range class failed run time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

When i try and sort columns in my script it returns the error Sort method of range class failed run time error 1004. Below I have included the script where this error is debugged as well as the declarations used in the script.

```
Set SbA = Worksheets("SumByAddress")
Set SbM = Worksheets("SumByMeterSize")
Set SFD = Worksheets("ShortFormData")
Counter = 2
premiseID = ""
RowNew = 2
TotalRows = SFD.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
TimeStart = Now
PrevUpdate = Now
SFD.Range("M15") = "Creating summation by address"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

SFD.Range("A:I").Sort , _
key2:=Range("A2"), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=True, _
key3:=Range("D2"), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify Key1 before specifying Key2 and Key3. E.G.:

```
Private Sub sortSheet(ByRef sh As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal rc As String)
  Dim lastRow As Long
  lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
  With sh.Range("A1:" + rc + CStr(lastRow))
    .Sort Key1:=sh.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=sh.Range("A1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
  End With
End Sub
```

Also, `Header` and `MatchCase` should be specified only once.